# TypeError Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence

Didn't exactly know what to title this question so I just named it the error I'm getting in console. The full error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceAt' of undefined

The problem with this is that I can see what the function accessing the `replaceAt` function is trying to do but do not know why. I have checks in place to stop this from happening but it still happens.

Basically I'm writing a text-based game in which a character and an AI battle on a 2D map (not an Array map). It happens when the AI tries to move off the map (only out the top and bottom that I've noticed) but I don't understand why.

The `replaceAt` function I am using is:

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, char) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + char + this.substr(index+char.length);
}
```

I am using this to edit strings in an array easily. I would also post the AI function however it is 447 lines long and don't think it should be posted here (if you think otherwise I'll edit it in).

My game can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/spedwards/R4F8L/

**Why is it that I get the TypeError when I have already got checks in stopping impossible actions?**

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken?

Comment: @kapa Adding debug messages in places where I think it could possibly go wrong. Didn't exactly help find the issue.

Comment: In your `replaceInAsciiMap` function, check for `array[row]` before calling `replaceAt`. `if (!array[row]) return;`.

Comment: Use the debugger in your browser, all modern ones have one. Make it stop on the error, examine the callstack, you can even do step by step execution.

Comment: @kapa Ahh thanks that helped! I was subtracting where I should have been adding and since I had copied bits of the code to account for all scenarios it was happening more than once but it's fixed now.

Comment: @spedwards Good to hear that! Please answer you own question then with the solution, or delete it if you think it will not help others.

Answer (score 0):

Your `replaceAt` function is fine,you are probably calling it on something else than a string (an `undefined` value it seems).
So put a debug/console statement just before it's called in your code.

Or do something like this:

```
if( typeof myVar === 'string' ){
  myVar.replaceAt(0,'a');
}
else {
  throw new Error('myVar is not a String'); // Or alert, etc. ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kapa, I figured out the problem I was having. Using the browser's debugging tools, I found out that I was subtracting 1 where I should have been adding it.